# Properties of Convex sets

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing, convex-analysis

I have the following properties about convex subsets of vector spaces that I need to prove. I use the following definitions. Let $X$ be a vector space and all other sets below are understood to be subsets of $X$. Define:

$$
\begin{align}
A+B &:= \{a+b \;|\; a\in A, b\in B \}\\
\alpha A &:= \{\alpha a\; | \; a\in A\}
\end{align}
$$

Then I want to prove that

1) If $A$ and $B$ are convex, then $A+B$ is also convex

2) A is convex if and only if $(s+t)A = sA+tA \quad \forall s,t \geq 0$

I suspect I am struggling mostly with the notation since I am used to a different definition for the sets above, but I have to use these to follow some theorems I am trying to understand. Since I am learning my proof writing on-the-go, any comment on style is also very much appreciated. Here are my attempts

1) Assume $A,B\subset X$ are convex. Let $a_1,a_2\in A$ and $b_1,b_2\in B$. Because $A$ and $B$ are convex, we have that $a_1t + (1-t)a_2 \in A\;$ and $\;b_1s + (1-s)b_2 \in B \;$ for all $t,s \in[0,1]$. **If we fix $t = s = t_0\in[0,1]$,** then the sum is also convex. Indeed, we have

$$
\begin{align}
a_1t_0 + (1-t_0)a_2 + b_1t_0 + (1-t_0)b_2 &= (a_1+b_1)t_0 + (1-t_0)(a_2+b_2) \\
&= c_1t_0 + (1-t_0)c_2 \in A+B, 
\end{align}
$$

where I have defined $c_1 = a_1+b_1$ and $c_2=a_2+b_2$ and it is clear from the definition of $A+B$ that $c_1,c_2\in A+B$. Therefore I have established that $A+B$ is also convext.

**Question**: Do I lose any generality by assuming the statement in bold letters above? I felt this was necessary because otherwise $s_0+t_0 \in[0,2]$

2) Assume $A$ is convex, then we want to prove inclusion both ways. Let $x\in (t+s)A$, and fix $t,s\in[0,1]$ then by definition of the set, $x=(t+s)a$ for some $a\in A$. Since $x$ is an element of $A\subset X$ (a vector space) we have $(t+s)a = ta + sa \; \cdots$

**then I become uneasy.** Superficially I say that clearly $ta\in tA$ and $sa\in sA$ therefore $x=ta + sa\in tA+sA$ and **done**. However, if I stare at the set definition of $tA+sA$ I think it means $\{ta_1 + sa_2|a_1,a_2\in A\}$ since both elements need not to be equal. Is this a problem?

Then for the other way around the set inclusion. Recalling our hypothesis that $A$ is convex, and letting $x\in(t_0A+s_0A)$ where we fixed $t_0,s_0\in[0,1]$, then we have $x=t_0a_1 + s_0a_2$ for some $a_1+a_2\in A$ not necessarily equal. Then I must show somehow that $x\in (t_0+s_0)A$, but that would require $a_1$ to be equal to $a_2$? I am not sure what can I deduce from the equality of the sets.

This is the kind of confusion these definitions bringing me, I am not sure whether I am being general or not; or how to manipulate the elements and the inclusions. Lastly, I have no idea how to get started for the converse of the property. I have more questions regarding other properties, but I think if I see how these come together in the above properties I should be ready to be on my own for now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In part $1)$ you are starting out wrong.  You need to show that if $x\in A+B$ and $y\in A+B,$ then $tx+(1-t)y\in A+B,$ for $0\le t\le 1$.  Then you say that by definition $x=a_1+b_1, \ y=a_2,b_2,$ for some $a_1,a_2\in A,$ etc.

The first part of $2)$ is correct.  You have shown $(s+t)A\subseteq sA+tA.$  This doesn't need convexity at all.  Also, you need not have $s,t\in [0,1].$  The remarks after, "Then I become uneasy," are confused.  You are right when you say **done**.  What you say about what the definition means is also correct.  It's also true that $a_1$ and $a_2$ can be different.  But they **need not be.**

So you need to show that if $A$ is convex, then $sA+tA\subseteq (s+t)A$  Now if $0\le s\le1$ and $t=1-s$ this is certainly true, by the definition of convexity.  So the problem is, how to reduce the general case to the case where $0\le s\le 1,\ t=1-s?$  Well, if $s$ and $t$ are nonnegative, consider$$s'=\frac{s}{s+t}\\t'=\frac{t}{s+t}$$

If $a_1,a_2\in A,$ then since $A$ is convex, we have that $sa_1'+t'a_2\in A$.  Then multiply both sides by $s+t$ to see that $sa_1+ta_2\in (s+t)A.$

You still have to handle the case where it is not true that $s\ge0,\  t\ge0,$ in particular when they have opposite signs.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I have a few questions about your answer. For 1) I followed your suggestion and got a proof. However, just for the sake of understanding and writing proofs, what exactly is wrong with starting the way I did? Finally, to see if I understood you, to show that $sA +tA \subseteq (s+t)A$, I should take $x\in sA+tA=\{sa_1+ta_2|a_1,a_2∈A\}$. If $a_1=a_2$, I can convince myself that containment follows. However what happens if $a_1\neq a_2$?

Comment: What's wrong with starting out as you did is just that it's a little confusing.  It  leads to a proof, but it's not so obvious what's going on.  Then when you say "fix t = s," my first though is, "You can't do that."  Well, yes you can, because of the way you started out, but it clearer the other way.  You need to show that a convex combination of two points in $A+B$ is back in $A+B,$ so just start out with such a convex combination.

Comment: As to the second point, we are given that $A$ is convex, so $sa_1+(1-s)a_2\in A$ As I tried to explain, the whole problem is how to deal with the case where we don't have $s+t=1\ 0\le s\le 1.$  We need to reduce the general case to the convex combination case.

Comment: Ok, I think I finally get the idea. This is one of those cases where we say "it suffices to show that..." in this case, if we are able to show that it holds for $|s|\leq 1$ and $t=1-s$ (do we restrict $t$ to something other than being positive?) then holds for the case where $s,t \geq 0$ since we can bring it down to the particular case. Now, I am sorry for making you state the obvious but how does your suggestion works?

Comment: @Fernando I'll add some explanation to my answer, but not much, because I'm falling asleep.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you so much for your patience! as for the case where it is not true that $s\geq 0$ and $t\geq 0$, I don't have to prove that (for now) since the property stated that it holds for all **positive** scalars $s$ and $t$ (I have edited my OP). Nevertheless, I should try it. I'll be around if I struggle with it ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's true.  If you can't prove it, look for a counterexample.  I've really got to go to bed :-).